# I need to know how to replace a water damaged wood rotten stud in a wall

Tags: bathroom, shower, studs, water-damage, old-house

I just bought a house built in 1930. The previous owners had a crack in the shower. I need to know how to replace the stud that holds up that wall as it is now rotten from water damage. The drywall is also rotten. The wall is not load bearing. And there's also water damage in the floor. My main concern at the moment is the stud. Also it should be noted that I stopped the leak for the time being.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Are you truly asking for a full project walk-through, or do you have a more specific concern? One or two studs can usually be removed from an interior wall without special care being taken with respect to structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut out the rotten drywall then use a reciprocating saw to cut out the old stud and replace with a new one. If it isn't load bearing and its only one stud this is easy. You may plan on also cutting out a portion of you bottom plate and replacing it if it also rotten.

Comment: Jon is right, the bottom plate is just as important as the stud.  However, instead of replacing stud you could also just sister in a new stud along side the existing questionable stud.

Comment: @PaulLogan Is right, you could definitely sister a new stud alongside the existing stud, you might consider this if the other side of the wall is finished. When I had to replace a bunch of rotten exterior studs this summer, I cut the rotted half of the old studs out before sistering a new stud next to it. But if the old stud is moldy or so wet you can't dry it out, then best remove it.